# Removing string parts between substrings when substrings occur multiple times in R

Tags: regex, r, string-parsing, strsplit

In a string

```
string="aaaaaaaaaSTARTbbbbbbbbbbSTOPccccccccSTARTddddddddddSTOPeeeeeee"
```

I would like to remove all parts that occur between START and STOP, yielding

```
"aaaaaaaaacccccccceeeeeee"
```

if I try with
`gsub("START(.*)STOP","",string)` this gives me
`"aaaaaaaaaeeeeeee"` though.

What would be the correct way to do this, allowing for multiple occurrences of START and STOP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `?` in there too.

```
gsub("START.*?STOP", "", string)
# [1] "aaaaaaaaacccccccceeeeeee"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not nearly as elegant as Ananda's answer, but there are some other ways using the stringr & plyr packages.

```
library(stringr)
library(plyr)

start <- ldply(str_locate_all(string, 'START'))[1, 1]
end <- ldply(str_locate_all(string, 'STOP'))
end <- end[nrow(end), 2]
expression <- str_sub(string, start, end)
str_replace(string, expression, '')
```